# Why does my windows phone app crash on button click?

Tags: c#

I am making a pet shop app for windows phone 7 in visual studios 2010. I am trying to get the items from one page that have already been copied to the temporary list in app.xaml (can see this in the debugger) to display in my other list on the basket page but when the button to direct to the basket page is clicked the application crashes. I did not use binding for any part of the app

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        thisApp.petBasket.Add(lstAllPets.SelectedItem as Pets);
        MessageBox.Show("Item added to the Basket");
    }
```

this is the code used to add the item to the temporary list

```
    public void ShowBasket()
    {
        if (thisApp.petBasket != null)
        {
            //show pets that have been added to the basket
            foreach (Pets currpet in thisApp.petBasket)
            {
                lstBasketItems.Items.Add(currpet.Name + "" + currpet.Gender + "" + currpet.Dob + "" + currpet.Category + "");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the code I am using to try and output the items but it makes the app crash

Does anyone know what the problem might be ?

Comment: I am not getting an error message when i run the code its  after you add the item to the basket and return to the homepage, when you click on the button to enter the basket page that is when the app crashes.

We discovered the line of code that makes it crash is inside the foreach loop to display the item as when it is commented out the app does not crash but when you put that line of code back in this is when the crash occurs but i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Your app might be crashing because your pet basket contains nulls.

```
thisApp.petBasket.Add(lstAllPets.SelectedItem as Pets);
```

If the selected item is not a `Pets` then `operator as` returns null and you put that in the list. Later on you just iterate without checking for nulls.

```
foreach (Pets currpet in thisApp.petBasket)
{
    lstBasketItems.Items.Add(currpet.Name + "" + currpet.Gender + "" + currpet.Dob + "" + currpet.Category + "");
}
```

You should check the selected item.

```
var pet = lstAllPets.SelectedItem as Pets;
if(pet != null)
    thisApp.petBasket.Add(pet);
```

You could also check `currpet` in your `foreach` loop.